# How to rewrite a path using .htaccess in WordPress with WPML?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wpml

I am currently adding Wordpress to a preexisting website. The original site content is to stay the same, so I installed Wordpress in a subfolder. So I have:

```
site.com (pre-existing site with a CMS)
site.com/blog (new Wordpress install)
```

The two CMS's are working fine, except that I need to add translations for all new Wordpress pages in french. I am using the WPML to enable the content to be translated. This is currently working. By default WPML is setup to present french content with a `/fr` added to the path:

```
site.com/blog becomes site.com/blog/fr
```

**Can I use .htaccess to rewrite the french URL from "/blog/fr" to "blogue"?**

I have tried adding .htaccess to my Wordpress directory but I'm really not sure what I should be writing as my rewrite conditions. Here's something I have tried but it is not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/fr/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog/fr%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /blogue/$1/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blogue/$1 [L]
```